# How to launch phantomjs in background?

Tags: phantomjs, debian

I'm trying to start a few phantomjs's scripts via cron, but as it waiting for `phantom.exit` (but i keep the pages open some time) in the first script, next scripts will not launch. Who knows solution of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linux you can run background processes by adding `&` at the end of the command.